# What is items and length in FileList in javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, filelist

i have a small app that upload a file:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var upload = function(){
    alert(document.getElementById('up_file').files[length]);
 };
</script>   
<body>

<input type='file' id='up_file'   />
<input type='button' value='Submit' onclick="upload();" />
    <p id="p"></p>

</body></html>
```

(very short)

please go on and copy and past this in your code editor and then open in google.
after you have opened this in your google browser then open its developer tool and write this in its console

`document.getElementById('up_file').files`

then it returns

*`FileList{0:File, Length:1, item:function}`* (please expand this object)

Now when we have to upload a file and want to get the name of that file then we have to write the code`document.getElementById('up_file').files[0].name` then it returns the file name says flower.jpg

## Case 1

when you have expanded the object `FileList` you have noticed that there is an property name `length`. Now when you type `document.getElementById('up_file').files[length]` then it should return 1 because when you had expanded `FileList` object you have seen their the property `length` is 1 but unexpectedly when we write `document.getElementById('up_file').files[length]` it returns another object then 1 ! that object is:

`File {webkitRelativePath: "", lastModifiedDate: Fri Aug 30 2013 13:42:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), name: "Creek.jpg", type: "image/jpeg", size: 264409…}`

and if we write `document.getElementById('up_file').files[length].name` it returns the same thing which is returned by `document.getElementById('up_file').files[0].name` that is the name of that file!

### Question:

1) why do javascript returns an object insted of the length of the number of the files when we write`document.getElementById('up_file').files[length]`?

## Case2

in that `FileList` object there is another property name `item` before you have expanded it but when you expand `FileList` object there is no property there with the name of `item` but when you further go on expanding the `FileList` object then you can see that `item`(may be this is a constrocter, may be, i am not sure, 50%).

see, `typeof __proto__` is a object then  item can be accessed by by using dot(.) nation but it always returned `undefined` when i write `__proto__.item`. i am not going to further explain because i am going out of my point...

### Question:

1) What is this Item?

2} how to get the properties of `__proto__` object?

---

well actually i so much confused and when i searched on internet then i get more puzzled!
You may dislike this question because it is... you know a bit confusing

---

Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementById('up_file').files[length]`

this problem is with accessing property of files.

There are two ways of accessing property of an object in JS.

`[]` array type notation -
either define the index using a literal string or a variable containing the string.

`files['length']`

or

```
var lengthProp = 'length';
files[lengthProp]
```

`.` notation -
simply access property with dot
`files.length`

1) the reason its returning object is because `files` is an Array. and the index length (javascript is reading it as a variable which is undefined) is actually undefined. for undefined index of an array browser is returning first item in the Array. which is the first File Object.

2) by expansion i think you mean viewing the object in console. `__proto__` property is actually accessor to prototype of the object. for `files` object the prototype is undefined. which the console displays as `__proto__` to the constructor. in JS its actually undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('up_file').files[length]

// should be:
document.getElementById('up_file').files.length
```

2} how to get the properties of `__proto__` object?

```
document.getElementById('up_file').files.item(0)
// return the first file

var files = document.getElementById('up_file').files;
console.log(files.__proto__ === Object.getPrototypeOf(files));
// -> true
```